# How to get running app information in iOS and Android using Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I am developing an app with flutter that requires information of all other running apps including start time, memory and all. Is there any API within Flutter to do that? Or, is it even possible?

Comment: In general, flutter exposes something called `platform_channel` to allow java/switch to communicate with dart. So you can get everything you could natively